# Git: Making edits in a local branch, to push back to remote repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, branch

Git newbie here!

This is a really basic question but I seem to be tying myself in knots trying to get my head around it. I'm still just at the 'playing around with repos' stage and starting to read some books. Please be nice :)

What do I do if... I have a remote repo. I clone it to my local area. I make a branch. I push the branch back so it exists in both places. I make some edits to the code in my local branch...

Do I then push the branch back to the remote branch, then merge the remote branch with the remote master, then push the remote master back to my local master? I'm confused what the correct/advised order is for merging in my changes. Is it better to push remote -> local, or to fetch or pull? I'll be working collaboratively, so other people might have changed the remote master while I've been working on my branch.

Do tracking branches just save time (so you don't have to be explicit when you say 'git push' - it knows where you probably want to push to)? I'm assuming they don't actually track changes e.g. updating the local master to match the remote one.

Thanks so much. I'm very confused but I really want to learn this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking good questions and you seem to be hitting on all the points of consideration.

1. clone remote
2. branch from upstream branch ( `origin/master` branched into `feature-123` let's say ) .  `git checkout master; git pull; git checkout -b feature-123`
3. write, test, commit changes.  `git add -u; git commit -v`
4. when in push-worthy state, push to origin, setting upstream for your local feature branch `git push --set-upstream origin feature-123`
5. when your branch is ready to merge to `origin/master`, checkout master, pull remote master ( this *won't* be done automatically, as you suspected) so that you're up to date, and merge your branch atop.  Push master upstream.  `git checkout master; git pull; git merge feature-123; git push`

If you have merge conflicts, such as a conflicting change made to master in the meantime, git will find it for you when you go to merge.  You can also pull master into your feature branch to stay up to date ( the sooner conflicts are found, the easier it generally is to resolve them).

And remember the golden rule for git newbies:  *never* force push, just create a new branch if it comes to that.   IF you don't force push you can always diff and find your changes.

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s really helpful! It’s slowly starting to make sense, I think I just need lots of practice :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what is your scenario, it's some like this:

You create a new branch from `master`(let's call it '`newFeature`'), made some changes on `newFeature` and want to merge't on `master`. If is that, i think the right way to do this is:

1. commit and push changes on `newFeature`
2. checkout master
3. merge `newFeature` into `master`
4. push `origin` to `master`

I'm assuming that you now how to do git stuffs, but if don't please tell me.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explicitly referenced upstream master or local master.  I think that's part of the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, referencing upstream master make this answer better, but more complex too. I consider that my answer is good enough, without complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Romulo, much appreciated. It was how to sync up the upstream and local files that had me confused